# syntax highlighter

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello i'm looking a dynamic syntax highlighter for PHP.

I'm not looking a highlighter to highlight a code snippet. looking a dynamic highlighter that highlights the code as i type.

**

I need this feature for online editor. (actually for the text-area element in a posting form.)

**

example: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find codemirror's pretty good: http://codemirror.net/

It has autocompletion, multiple syntaxes in one page (think html+js+css), and lots of languages.

This is what [google](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/), [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and others are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need a IDE such as Netbeans or Eclipse. I sure there is others out there  as well.

Comment: Sydwell, not looking for an IDE. I need this feature for online editor. (actually for the text-area element in a posting form.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. you should update your question so that it reflects that. Also add a tag for php.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a template editor in a CMS which uses the following library for this task:

http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/

> Main features:
>
> Easy to integrate, only one script include and one function call
> Tabulation support (allow to write well formated source code)
> Customizable real-time syntax highlighting (currently: PHP, CSS, Javascript, Python, HTML, XML, VB, C, CPP, SQL, Pascal, Basic, Brainf*ck, and probably more...)